# Execute 2 php-cli scripts and allow them to be stopped/started by a third script

Tags: php, bash, command-line-interface

I currently have 2 php cli scripts that run in the background on my server.  I would like the ability to allow a 3rd script to kill 1 (or both) scripts and restart them again.  My current method involves creating a shell script with:

```
#!/bin/bash
nohup php script1.php &
nohup php script2.php &
```

And when I need to restart them, I run ps and kill them manually and re-run the shell script.

Is there a way that I can start/restart these scripts from a third php script when needed?  I would imagine it would involve recording the pid's to a file and having the 3rd script read the pid's and kill them from there, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: something like: http://www.bram.us/2013/11/11/run-a-php-script-as-a-servicedaemon-using-start-stop-daemon/

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution.  I created a couple of functions in my 3rd script to "start" and "restart" the other two php scripts like this:

```
function launchscripts() {
   global $pid1, $pid2;
   $cmd1 = "/usr/bin/php /home/of/the/script1.php";
   $pid1 = exec("nohup $cmd1 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
   $cmd2 = "/usr/bin/php /home/of/the/script2.php";
   $pid2 = exec("nohup $cmd2 > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!");
   return true;
}

function restartscripts() {
   global $pid1, $pid2;
   exec("kill $pid1");
   exec("kill $pid2");
   launchscripts();
   return true;
}
```

There are probably much better ways of doing this, but I'm not very good with PHP.  This seems to work, so I'll stick with it.

One thing I didn't mention earlier that I'm thinking was probably important, was that my 3rd script would be constantly running when the other two are, that's why global variables will work for this.